# Best remote desktop protocol for windows client and ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop

I am trying to remote desktop from windows to ubuntu. I know of several good software available out there. Plus that using 2d desktops like xfce,lxde,mate hangs less over internet as transfer is easier. What i want to ask here is if i don't want to use GUI software like teamviewer, nomachine which do the grunt work for you and want to remote desktop from scratch using a protocol like vnc,rdp etc. Tutorials are already available on youtube. Which is the best?

The available protocols that i know of are:  RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP, SPICE and SSH .

Criteria are there is a windows client and ubuntu server. I am already using 2d desktops because 3d ones like cinnamon, unity, kde have flaky transfer over my internet speeds. So which protocol is the best to transfer seamless and smoothest desktop data over moderate speed internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend X2go. Based on SSH, it is most secure from the above mentioned.

[Link](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php)

You can choose between multiple desktops, KDE,Xfce,Gnome,Openbox, Unity, Mate etc.

PKI is supported as well.

https://gyazo.com/faaa8fa946b0528d02f51386946374a4

Simple, fast and secure.